# Can I do swift extensions with inner generics?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, realm

I want to make RxSwift and Realm work together, and I tried to build functions to help me.
For example, instead of using the function sorted on Results objects (which give you sorted Results), I want to build a function that do so directly on Observable>.
Thanks to the ObservableType protocol, I managed to do it on non-generic object, but can't find a way to do it on a generic way

Here is my actual code, which works only on specific Object :

```
public extension ObservableType where E == Results<MyRealmObject> {

    public func sorted(key: String, ascending: Bool = true) -> Observable<Results<MyRealmObject>>
    {
        return self.map { $0.sorted(key, ascending: ascending) }

    }
}
```

If I changed MyRealmObject by T, the compilers tell me that T is undeclared.
I've tried many syntaxes but none are working, and I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have these frameworks, but I'm guessing the types are analogous to the following:

```
protocol ObservableType {
    associatedtype E
}

class Observable<T> : ObservableType {
    typealias E = T
    init() {}
}

enum Results<T> {
    case None
    case Some(T)
}
```

... in which case you could try:

```
extension ObservableType {

    func sorted <T where Self.E == Results<T>> (/* ... */) -> Observable<Results<T>> {
        return /* sorted */ Observable()
    }
}
```

... which works:

```
let o = Observable<Results<Int>>()
o.sorted() // Observable<Results<Int>>
```

... but is not optimal because:

```
let x = Observable<Int>()
x.sorted() // compile-time error: Generic parameter `T` could not be infered
```

... which you'd prefer to say `Value of type 'Observable<Int>' has no member 'sorted'`. And though the error is at least thrown at compile time, I think your own approach is still preferable.

**Just an afterthought based on @Denis Laboureyras' comments**

Whilst trying out my solution, Denis could not access the value of type `E` as `Results<T>` without casting because the `extension` does not constrain the type of `self` but only the parameters of the method. All these issues go away in case of a free function (though I appreciate this is not ideal either):

```
protocol ObservableType {
    associatedtype E
    func map <X> (_: E -> X) -> Observable<X>
}

class Observable<T> : ObservableType {
    typealias E = T
    init() {}
    func map <X> (f: E -> X) -> Observable<X> {
        return Observable<X>(/* with f(e) */)
    }
}

class Results<T> {
    func sort(/* ... */) -> Results<T> {
        return /* sorted */ self
    }
}

func sort <O: ObservableType, T where O.E == Results<T>> (o: O/* ... */) -> Observable<Results<T>> {
    return o.map{ $0.sort() }
}

let o = Observable<Results<Int>>()
sort(o) // Observable<Results<Int>>
```

Comment: Hello milos. Your assumption was correct on the Observable class, it is defined like that. But Results is not an enum, it's a plain class (class Results<T: Object>). Your code can compile with nothing into the function. But I can't use the Results sorted function inside my new function.  Anyway I think I will give up on that, generics protocols give me headaches...

Comment: Just remembered that the syntax for a free function is not limited like that, so I added that option to the answer for completeness. Of course, I understand that this will not quite scratch the itch either...

Comment: OK thanks for your update, I've tested your code and it's working, even that's not quite I wanted. But it seems that's the best we can do :)

Comment: Your are welcome. One of these days I will dive into `RxSwift` and if that opens my eyes to a better solution I'll try and remember to update my answer. Sorry I could not be of better use at present...